# Vuex 3 vs Vuex 4 getters: change in behaviour if applied to nested objects?

Tags: vuejs3, vuex4

I used to be able to apply a reactive getter to a nested method inside an object instance stored in my `vuex` state, but this doesn't appear to work anymore.

In this particular case, it was a `mapbox` instance which was created and then stored inside the `vuex` v3 store's state. I could then share this instance amongst various components and could also watch the instance for changes via reactive getters.

For example:

```js
state: {
  mapInstance: null, // <- gets assigned with a mapbox instance
  // mapInstance contains a method called "getZoom()"
},
getters: {
  zoom: (state) => (state.mapInstance ? state.mapInstance.getZoom() : null),
}
```

However, the reactive getters no longer work for this use case in `vuex` v4.

I'm assuming something has changed in the internals of `vuex` v3 vs. v4: is there a way to deliberately expose certain nested properties or methods to reactive getters in `vuex` v4?

Comment: Your `state` is called `mapInstance` but you're trying to reference `mapBox`.  Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, typo, fixed...

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this problem, it works fine in Vuex 4 when I commit to set `mapInstance` with a plain object having a `getZoom` method.  Maybe you can try to reproduce it at https://codesandbox.io